# How can I generate test coverage of untested files on my flutter tests?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I'm making Widget and Unit testing on my app, I make the tests normally, according to the [basic guides](https://flutter.io/docs/testing), and to generate the coverage I use:

`flutter test --coverage`

However I just can see the coverage of the files **directly tested**, I'd like to see the other files (with 0% of coverage), then I could check the real coverage of my code.

Is there a way for doing that?

Comment: same here. i found the same problem, the coverage only show which i have tested.

Comment: did u solve this problem now?

Comment: Not solved yet, if I get some solution I'm gonna post here.

Comment: i find out how to achieve this now, you must import all (test and untested) files in your *_test.dart file.

import lib/* from ....

Comment: Interesting, that is a way to mitigate, however doesn't solve the problem, because we still need to make something to make all the files appear on tests, that way we just change the need to make tests to the need to import the files inside some test.

Answer (score 14):

I have created a [small helper script](https://github.com/priezz/dart_full_coverage) to help with the full coverage report generation. It scans your `lib` directory for `*.dart` files (excluding `*.g.dart`) and imports them into the generated `test/coverage_test.dart` file. Having this generated file coverage analyser will go through the whole project next time you run it. To use the script:

1. Clone it to any location

   ```sh
   wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/priezz/dart_full_coverage/master/dart-coverage-helper
   ```
2. Make it executable

   ```sh
   chmod +x dart-coverage-helper
   ```
3. Ensure that the location of the script is in your `PATH` environment variable (or just put it into the root of your project).
4. Run from the root of your Dart/Flutter project

   ```sh
   dart-coverage-helper
   ```

Then generate the coverage report as usual

```sh
flutter test --coverage # for Flutter project
# or
pub run test_coverage   # for Dart project
```